# Mulching Build-Up Under Mower Deck

Tags: lawn-mower

Does anyone know of any attachments/accessories that could be attached to the mulching blades, that would remove the under deck mulch build-up as the blades turn???

Thanks in advance
Ken S.

Answer (score 1):

Normally the manufacturer puts a lot of research into how to best use the equipment for specific purposes. Unless they publish details of extras there might not be any apart from the usual correct mulching blades plus adaptations to restrict or close off any discharge chutes. It's the blade design which keeps the clippings suspended in the rotation chamber under the deck so that they can be cut finely.

If the clippings stick to the underside this generally means too much moisture. In theory a bit of moisture is good since the clippings will be heavier and more susceptible to cut by the blades. On the other hand it is the wet that causes them to stick to each other and the deck and accumulate. Moisture can come from two places - natural sap in the grass, and surface water from dew, rain, irrigation and so on. If the grass can be cut perfectly dry of surface moisture then a thin layer of mashed grass may accumulate under the deck which is not a problem. Surface moisture can cause severe clumping.

A good guide to dryness of grass is when walking through the grass in boots. If the toes become dark or shiny from moisture then there will likely be clogging. Surface moisture is much worse in the mornings after a dew or after a rain and in cool temperatures. A good time is in the cool of the afternoon when humidity is low. Make sure to raise the height of the deck to cut small clippings - when the clippings are too long for the mower to handle then the cloud of clippings can become very dense.

Comment: Hi Colin, Thank you for the info. It is more than wet this year in East Tennessee and I wait till later in the day to mow. However, there are still some areas where the front wheels on my zero turn become wet looking...  I was hoping that someone would know of an attachment that mounted to the blade, like an adjustable brush attachment, that would sweep the moist grass clippings from the underside of the mower before they attach and build up...  Seems to me like an opportunity for someone to invent....   Thanks again...